What is the difference between IF and IFF in spark SQL?
The documentation for both functions is practically identical.
See IF and IFF.
When running (in DBR 13.3, though that should not matter):
SELECT
    IF(1 = 1, 'a', 'b'),  IF(1 = 0, 'a', 'b'),
    IFF(1 = 1, 'a', 'b'), IFF(1 = 0, 'a', 'b')

It results in:

Is there any difference in how these operations behave?

The documentation literally says IFF is a synonym for IF.  There is no difference,

Wow, don't know how I could have missed that... Thanks

As they have mentioned in the documentation iff is a synonym for if, it is the same as the where and filter


I figured that the column names already showed a hint of the execution plan.
EXPLAIN
    SELECT
        IF(1 = 1, 'a', 'b'), IF(1 = 0, 'a', 'b'),
        IFF(1 = 1, 'a', 'b'), IFF(1 = 0, 'a', 'b')

Results in:
== Physical Plan ==
*(1) Project [a AS (IF((1 = 1), a, b))#9622, b AS (IF((1 = 0), a, b))#9623, a AS (IF((1 = 1), a, b))#9624, b AS (IF((1 = 0), a, b))#9625]
+- *(1) Scan OneRowRelation[]

Where you can see that both IF and IFF refer to the exact same operation: IF.
